# How to write a package.json file so that all dependencies are downloaded with "npm install"

Tags: node.js, npm

I wrote a simple application using node. It depends on express, mongodb and mongoose (easy).
So, I created a file called `package.json` and put this in it:

```
{
  "name": "booking-dojo",
  "description": "Booking dojo app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "*"
  }
}
```

I then ran `npm install`, expecting npm to install those modules *and* their dependencies.
The result was disappointing:

```
booking-dojo@0.0.1 /home/merc/Synced/Development/Bookings/app/server
├─┬ express@3.0.0rc3 
│ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ ├─┬ connect@2.4.3 
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0 
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11 
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1 
│ │ └── qs@0.4.2 
│ ├── cookie@0.0.4 
│ ├── crc@0.2.0 
│ ├── debug@0.7.0 
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0 
│ ├── methods@0.0.1 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3 
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4 
│ └─┬ send@0.0.3 
│   └── mime@1.2.6 
├─┬ mongodb@1.1.4 
│ └── bson@0.1.1 
└─┬ mongoose@3.0.3 
  ├── hooks@0.2.1 
  └── ms@0.1.0
```

I am confused by this, as I *know* that `express` needs `jade`  (and much more), and `mongoose` needs `mongodb`.
If I go into `node_modules/jade` and run `npm install`, the result from the main tree is very different:

```
booking-dojo@0.0.1 /home/merc/Synced/Development/Bookings/app/server
├─┬ express@3.0.0rc3 
│ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ ├─┬ connect@2.4.3 
│ │ ├── bytes@0.1.0 
│ │ ├── formidable@1.0.11 
│ │ ├── pause@0.0.1 
│ │ └── qs@0.4.2 
│ ├─┬ connect-redis@1.4.1 
│ │ └─┬ redis@0.7.2 
│ │   └── hiredis@0.1.14 
│ ├── cookie@0.0.4 
│ ├── crc@0.2.0 
│ ├── debug@0.7.0 
│ ├── ejs@0.8.2 
│ ├── fresh@0.1.0 
│ ├── github-flavored-markdown@1.0.1 
│ ├─┬ hjs@0.0.4 
│ │ └── hogan.js@2.0.0 
│ ├─┬ jade@0.27.2 
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ ├── methods@0.0.1 
│ ├── mkdirp@0.3.3 
│ ├─┬ mocha@1.4.0
│ │ ├── diff@1.0.2 
│ │ ├── growl@1.5.1 
│ │ └─┬ jade@0.26.3 
│ │   └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ ├── range-parser@0.0.4 
│ ├─┬ send@0.0.3 
│ │ └── mime@1.2.6 
│ ├── should@1.1.0 
│ ├─┬ stylus@0.29.0 
│ │ └── cssom@0.2.5 
│ └─┬ supertest@0.0.1 
│   └─┬ superagent@0.5.0 
│     ├── emitter-component@0.0.1 
│     ├── formidable@1.0.9 
│     ├── mime@1.2.5 
│     └── qs@0.4.2 
├─┬ mongodb@1.1.4 
│ └── bson@0.1.1 
└─┬ mongoose@3.0.3 
  ├── hooks@0.2.1 
  └── ms@0.1.0
```

So, `express` has *grown* a lot. It looks like `npm install` is only loading *some* of the dependencies of the sub-modules.

Can somebody please shed some light on this? Why are some dependencies missing? Am I doing something wrong? (likely)

Thanks!

Merc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was provided by Brandon in a comment to another answer:

"Another thing to note is that if a package depends on a module that can be resolved further up in the dependency chain, it will. For example, since you have mongodb in your package.json, Mongoose doesn't need to install its own mongodb. – Brandon Tilley 2 days ago

Thank you Brandon! (And this is the answer...)

Answer (score 38):

You are confused about at least 2 points.

First, express does not depend on jade, as you can see by reading the `node_modules/express/package.json` file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "2.4.2",
    "commander": "0.6.1",
    "range-parser": "0.0.4",
    "mkdirp": "0.3.3",
    "cookie": "0.0.4",
    "crc": "0.2.0",
    "fresh": "0.1.0",
    "methods": "0.0.1",
    "send": "0.0.3",
    "debug": "*"
  }
```

Express does, however, work *with* jade *if* it is available, as well as many other template engines. So to fix this list jade as a dependency in your package.json file and you'll be fine.

Second, npm only installs node packages, not third party things like mongodb. You need to install mongodb and any other dependencies that are not npm modules using other means (`apt-get`, `yum`, manual install, etc).

So npm DOES install dependencies recursively, but only npm modules.

Comment: Another thing to note is that if a package depends on a module that can be resolved further up in the dependency chain, it will. For example, since you have `mongodb` in your package.json, Mongoose doesn't need to install its own `mongodb`.

Comment: Brandon, this *is* the answer. I just figured it out not long ago. Basically, it doesn't install MongoDb under Mongoose because it's resolved further up. Since this *is* the actual answer, can you please add it as a proper answer, rather than a comment, so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Peter Good point, applications *generated* by express will have however express as a dependency BTW. My question, "why are some dependencies missing?", has the simple answer (provided by Brandon) "They are missing because they are resolved further up in the dependency tree". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

use  this  sample

```html
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main":"test.js",
  "author":"Test",
  "description": "For test ",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "latest",
    "mongoose": "latest"
  }

}
```